# how to understand foreach loop in powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi every one I am new to power shell and trying to make sense about for each loop but I don't understand what does + $ means in the below script and why they are used together

```
$names = "jones","mike","Ash"
foreach ($name in $names)
{
    "$name = " + $name.length
}
```

Comment: I just copied this script from google but trying to make sense of for loop. What is $name in for each loop, i am confused because the variable we declared is $names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it is ***PowerShell***. There is no space and observe the capitalization of letters.

Second, RTFM. There is a lot of documentation on Technet. Make use of that. There is built-in help. Read `Help about_*` topics.

Coming to your question, the `foreach` loop iterates over all collection. In your example, `$names` is an array of strings. An array is a collection.

In your example, when the `foreach` loop iterates over the collection, it copies each item in the collection to another variable called `$name`.

```
foreach ($name in $names) {}
```

Inside the `foreach` loop, you can use the `$name` variable to retrieve the value stored in the item. So, the following code will print the values in the collection.

```
foreach ($name in $names) {
    $name
}
```

`$name` is a string. So, `$name.Length` gives us the length of that string.

`+` is an arithmetic operator. It can be used to concatenate strings. In this case, `$name + $name.length` will result in the value getting appended with the length.

Here is the modified example with output:

```
$names = "jones","mike","Ash"
foreach ($name in $names)
{
    $name + $name.Length
}

jones5
mike4
Ash3
```

Finally, coming to your example and the output:

```
$names = "jones","mike","Ash"
foreach ($name in $names)
{
    "$name = " + $name.Length
}

jones = 5
mike = 4
Ash = 3
```

I hope this provides some explanation for you on what the example is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see this step by step:

```
$names = "jones","mike","Ash"
```

This declares an array with three string items and stores it in the $names variable.

```
foreach ($name in $names) { }
```

This is a loop that iterates through all items in the $names array variable. Each item is "copied" into the "$name" variable, so when you're working with `$name`, you are working with the current item in the loop.

```
"$name = " + $name.length
```

This outputs the contents of the $name variable and the "length" property of the object represented by $name. If you recall, we declared an array of string items, in other words string objects. Strings objects have properties and methods, one of those properties is the `length` property that tells how long the string is.

The notation is a bit odd, though. In PowerShell, variables embedded into string literals (e.g. `"start $name end"` will be replaced with their string value, so `"start $name end"` will become `start jones end` for the first item. However, you can't just write `"start $name.length end"`, so in this example the author used + to concatenate (append) the two strings. An alternative solution to that would be `"$name = $($name.length))"`: this way a single string literal would contain both the string and its length property.